# LibreOffice - Items missing when document is saved in .docx

Tags: libreoffice

I am using the pre-installed LibreOffice 3.4 with Ubuntu 11.10.

Using the drawing tool, I draw a few flowcharts, with the default flowchart symbols.

If I save my work in odt format, it will be no problem.

However, when I save my work in docx format, close and re-open the file, all my flowcharts are missing.

I've tried doc format as well. And no matter I draw the flowchart directly, or put them inside a frame, same result.

I don't have a personal printer, the printer I use is connect to a Windows machine, and its Microsoft Word cannot read odt file, because the admin does not update the suite.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Anyone encountering this page in 2014 should note that this question is over 2 years old and the Ubuntu version (and LibreOffice) version in question is now retired.  The issues described in the question may have changed in later versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formats are different and partially incompatible. The best way to accomplish this is to make a PDF file. There should be a PDF button on your toolbar. Just make a PDF and you can print your file anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As for why this happens -- I've had similar problems with LibreOffice not saving images in docx format. Essentially, the problem seems to be that the specification of the file formats of doc and docx are either very long or not actually available when the Libreoffice team created the filters to create doc/docx files. As such doc/docx files are not guaranteed to be handled perfectly.

See the LibreOffice Q&A: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/16247/why-does-libreoffice-still-have-such-poor-formatting-of-docx-and-some-doc-files-despite-the-claims-of-improvement/

I agree with Scott that making a PDF file will solve your printing problems, though obviously if you need to make any last minute edits it is not as ideal. For images the doc format seems to work fine though.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.